# Azure fails when I try to deploy through GitHub

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, build

I get this error when I deploy my deploy.sh file to azure.
How can I fix this ?

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs'.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs'.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.51202.2583\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd bash deploy.sh
```

My website is using NodeJS as taskrunner, but the build scripts fails before it even reaches the build part.

This is the code that fails:

```
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/nodejs" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi
```

I'm on a mac and the the code that fails was generated by the azure-cli package.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates,

> Error: Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\home\site\repository\nodejs'.

So please change `"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/nodejs"` to `"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE"` and redeploy it.

Or you can regenerate the `deploy.sh` file with the command below in Azure CLI,

```
azure site deploymentscript --node -t bash
```